# Does redis process commands serially?

Tags: redis

I have to write a async client to communicate with redis server for some reason.

For each connection, does redis processes commands serially in the order in which they
were received and sends responses in the same order ?

Because I am going to use a queue to store commands in client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As it is [single threaded](http://redis.io/topics/faq), it will process your command one by one.